# Como obtener los valores de un array que está en un objeto el cuál está en otro array?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Cuál es la manera correcta de obtener los valores contenidos en un array el cuál hace parte de las propiedades de un objeto que se encuentra en otro array?
Es decir, si tengo algo como esto:

```js
const functions = [
  {
    function: "Liderazgo",
    id: 1,
    selected: "true",
    ids: [
      0: 5,
      1: 11,
      2: 17,
      3: 50
     ],
   },
   {
     function: "Financiero",
     id: 2,
     selected "true",
     ids: [
      0: 20,
      1: 53,
      2: 80,
     ],
   },
 ];
```

Necesito extraer los ids y tener como resultado algo así: `[5, 11, 17, 50, 20, 53, 80]`

No doy con la manera correcta de hacerlo!

Comment: ¿y que has instentado? Por favor presioná [edit] y agrega lo que has intentado. Sin saber lo que has intentado es difícil poder ayudarte a encontrar donde esta el error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para acceder a un miembro de un objeto utilizas la notación `objeto.miembro`.

Para acceder a un elemento de un arreglo, utilizas la notación `arreglo[indice]`.

Si quieres acceder a un miembro que es un arreglo de uno solo de los elementos de un arreglo de objetos, puedes usar la notación `arregloExterior[indice].arregloInterior`, por ejemplo:

```
functions[1].ids
```

Te dará el arreglo de *ids* del segundo elemento del arreglo functions. De manera similar, puedes acceder a cualquiera de los elementos de ese arreglo por su índice, por ejemplo:

```
functions[1].ids[2]
```

Te devolverá el número 80, que es el tercer elemento del arreglo de `ids` del segundo elemento del arreglo `functions`.

Dicho esto, para obtener el resultado que buscas puedes valerte del método [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) para recorrer los elementos del arreglo `functions` y del método [`concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) para ir *mezclando* los arreglos de cada uno de los elementos en un nuevo arreglo de resultados.

OJO, que el JSON que publicas en la pregunta es inválido, al menos en chrome, he quitado los que supongo que eran índices de los elementos del arreglo para que el ejemplo a continuación funcione; de lo contrario da un error de sintaxis en el caracter `:` del primer elemento del arreglo de la primera *función*.

El código:

```js
const functions = [ 
  {
    function: "Liderazgo",
    id: 1,
    selected: "true",
    ids: [
      5,
      11,
      17,
      50
     ]
  },
  {
    function: "Financiero",
    id: 2,
    selected: "true",
    ids: [
      20,
      53,
      80
     ]
  }
 ];
 
console.log(functions[0].ids);
console.log(functions[1].ids[2]);

let resultado = [];
functions.forEach(fn => resultado = resultado.concat(fn.ids));
console.log(resultado);
```

Puedes probar el código directamente en el navegador haciendo clic en el botón *Ejecutar*.

Resultado en mi consola:

```
[
  5,
  11,
  17,
  50,
  20,
  53,
  80
]
```

Comment: Ahhh claro!! Tiene tiene todo el sentido del mundo!!! Marco tu respuesta como respondida. Gracias!!